# Drawing color tiles using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

Hi good people of StackExchange, I want to draw a colored tile using Tikz. Roughly to represent the percentage three kind of things have in comparison to their total. The picture I want can be produced using the following.

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\colorTiles[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[ultra thick](0,0) rectangle (1,0.5);
      \draw[fill = red](0, 0) rectangle (0.3, 0.5);
      \draw[fill = green](0.3, 0) rectangle (0.7, 0.5);
      \draw[fill = purple](0.7, 0) rectangle(1, 0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }

\colorTiles{}
```

[image]

Now my question is, how can I define the new command so that I don't have to adjust the proportions every time? Ideally, I just need to use

```
\colorTile{0.3, 0.5, 0.2}
```

And I should get a tile with 30% red, 50% green, and 20% purple. I'm not familiar with Tikz so please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! The following produces such bars. The syntax is as simple as

```
\pic{color tile={0.3, 0.5, 0.2}};
```

The colors are stored in a list and can be adjusted, as illustrated in the following example. The width is stored in a pgf key and can also be adjusted.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/color tile/.style={code={
 \path (0,0) coordinate (aux);
 \foreach \XX [count=\YY starting from 0] in {#1} 
 {\pgfmathsetmacro\mycol{{\LstCols}[\YY]}
 \draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width},color=\mycol]
 (aux) -- ++(\XX,0) coordinate (aux);}
 \draw[thick] (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width}/2) rectangle
 (aux|-0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width}/2);
 }},color tile/.cd,width/.initial=5mm]
 \edef\LstCols{"red","green","purple","blue"} %< adjust and extent if needed
 \path pic{color tile={0.3, 0.5, 0.2}} (3,0) pic{color tile={0.3,0.6,0.4, 0.5}};
 \edef\LstCols{"orange","purple","yellow","red","blue"} %< adjusted and extended list
 \path  (1,-2) pic{color tile={0.3,0.6,0.4, 0.5,0.8}};
 \tikzset{color tile/width=1cm}
 \path  (1,-4) pic{color tile={0.3,0.6,0.4, 0.5,0.8}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment on a command: here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/color tile/.style={code={
 \edef\LstCols{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/colors}}
 \path (0,0) coordinate (aux);
 \foreach \XX [count=\YY starting from 0] in {#1} 
 {\pgfmathsetmacro\mycol{{\LstCols}[\YY]}
 \draw[line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width},color=\mycol]
 (aux) -- ++(\XX,0) coordinate (aux);}
 \draw[thick] (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width}/2) rectangle
 (aux|-0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color tile/width}/2);
 }},color tile/.cd,width/.initial=1em,
 colors/.initial={"red","green","purple","blue"}}
\newcommand{\ColorTile}[2][]{\tikz{\pic[color tile/.cd,#1]{color tile={#2}};}} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ColorTile{0.3, 0.5, 0.2} & ABC \\
\ColorTile{0.1, 0.2, 0.7} & UVW \\
\ColorTile[colors={"red","green","blue"}]{0.3, 0.5, 0.2}  & XYZ\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. If you want to "stretch" the tile, use `xscale`, e.g. `\path  pic[xscale=5]{color tile={0.3,0.2,0.5}};`. You can also rotate it etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Is it possible to use this inline with texts? In fact I was going to put these in tables. Can your answer be adapted for that? Thanks again!

Comment: @skyphantasy Of course, I added a proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this just in case someone would need it:

```
\newcommand\colorTiles[3]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick](0,0) rectangle (2,0.5);
    \draw[fill = red](0, 0) rectangle (#1 * 2, 0.5);
    \draw[fill = green](#1 * 2, 0) rectangle (#2 * 2 + #1 * 2, 0.5);
    \draw[fill = purple](#2 * 2 + #1 * 2, 0) rectangle(#3 * 2 + #2 * 2 + #1 * 2, 0.5);
    \draw[fill = gray](#3 * 2 + #2 * 2 + #1 * 2, 0) rectangle(2, 0.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then we can put `\colorTiles{0.2}{0.5}{0.1}` inline.